# Understanding the difference between self invoking functions statements

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

Please explain, why does this statement

```
function f(){}()
```

throw an exception, but absolutely the same thing inside of brackets

```
(function f(){}())
```

does not

Comment: Because that's the required syntax, you have to add parentheses around the function to indicate that it is a function expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser interprets the former as a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and the later as a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

Why? To understand we need to look in section 11.1.6 and 12.4 of ECMA-262 3rd edition. Section 12.4 states that "an ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration." This tells us that the `function f(){}()` must be a function declaration, and the `()` is invalid syntax. The reason this statement is an expression is because of the grouping operator in section 11.1.6 (aka the parenthesis) forces this function to be treated as an expresion.